# Adding an order column where the value is the position in the table considering an grouping id(db2)

Tags: sql, db2

I need to add an order column to following table:

```
| Id | DepId | Name  | 
|----|-------|-------|
|  1 |   1   |  Bill |
|  2 |   1   |  Joe  |
|  3 |   2   |  Jack |
|  4 |   1   |  Jill |
```

It should become:

```
| Id | DepId | Name  | Order |
|----| ------|-------|-------|
|  1 |   1   |  Bill |   1   |
|  2 |   1   |  Joe  |   2   |
|  3 |   2   |  Jack |   1   |
|  4 |   1   |  Jill |   3   |
```

I know let's use order by id, and don't worry about such order column, but in this case the difficulty increases when entries are shifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the ROW_NUMBER() OLAP function...

Instead of actually adding the column to the physical table, you could (should) create a view:

```
create view myview as
 (select Id, DepId, Name
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DepId ORDER BY DepId, ID) as OrderNbr
  from mytable
 )
```